# String split on digit and space

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

How do I split a long string by the first space unless the second word is lower case?

```
df                             col
0     Apple The fruit. 20 Banana tree A fruit. 30  Carrot A Vegetable. 40
```

Expected Output:

```
df
  fruit          definition      page
0 Apple          The fruit.       20
1 Banana tree    A fruit.         30
2 Carrot         A Vegetable.     40
```

```
df.col.str.split('(\d+)').explode()

0 Apple The fruit.
0  20
0 Banana tree A fruit.
0  30
0 Carrot A Vegetable.
0  40
```

```
df.col.split(".", expand = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

new_df[["fruit", "definition"]] = df.col.str.split("\d+")\
    .str[:-1].explode()\
    .str.strip()\
    .str.extract(r'^([A-Z][^A-Z]*)(.*)')

new_df["page"] = df.col.str.findall('\d+').explode()
new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop = True)
```

```
new_df
          fruit    definition page
0        Apple     The fruit.   20
1  Banana tree       A fruit.   30
2       Carrot   A Vegetable.   40
```

---

Documentation

1. [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)
2. [`pandas.Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html)
3. [`pandas.Series.str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html)
4. [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)
5. [`pandas.Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html)
6. [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)